# UWP Subscription Ad on is not returning

Tags: uwp

i use the below code to get subscription product according to the msdn [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/enable-subscription-add-ons-for-your-app) although other durable adons are returned. actual subscription ad on isnt returned by GetAssociatedStoreProductsAsync function.
my app is in the store and subscription is also in the store as shown below.

what is the problem here? can somebody give me some help?

[image]

```
private async Task<StoreProduct> GetSubscriptionProductAsync()
{
    // Load the sellable add-ons for this app and check if the trial is still 
    // available for this customer. If they previously acquired a trial they won't 
    // be able to get a trial again, and the StoreProduct.Skus property will 
    // only contain one SKU.
    StoreProductQueryResult result =
        await context.GetAssociatedStoreProductsAsync(new string[] { "Durable" });

    if (result.ExtendedError != null)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Something went wrong while getting the add-ons. " +
            "ExtendedError:" + result.ExtendedError);
        return null;
    }

    // Look for the product that represents the subscription.
    foreach (var item in result.Products)
    {
        StoreProduct product = item.Value;
        if (product.StoreId == subscriptionStoreId)
        {
            return product;
        }
    }

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("The subscription was not found.");
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from Xavier Xie-Msft is also correct indeed but not in my case because i was following all the steps as he mentioned. actual answer to my question is,

Although on the developer center, it displays in the store(like in my screenshot), it is not returned by In app purchases api for another day or more. An email is sent saying "your ad on is in the store", this email is usually sent after a day from it is shown "in the store" on the dev center. email is the exact confirmation that ad on is really in the store. It is quite confusing why dev center display in the store while email is the correct confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

It's good to know that you're following the steps on the [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/enable-subscription-add-ons-for-your-app) document to enable subscription add-ons for your app. But I still have some points to confirm with you.

1. To enable the purchase of subscription add-ons in your app, your project must target Windows 10 Anniversary Edition (10.0; Build 14393) or a later release in Visual Studio (this corresponds to Windows 10, version 1607), and it must use the APIs in the **Windows.Services.Store** namespace to implement the in-app purchase experience
2. Test the in-app purchase implementation of your subscription in your app. You'll need to download your app once from the Store to your development device to use its license for testing. See our [testing guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/in-app-purchases-and-trials#testing) for more details.

Please first check the above key points.

Comment: thanks for your reply. it seems like my problem is resolved and today i am getting the subscription when i debug. Just a strange behavior, for the above subscription I am getting 2 skus with 2 different StoreId. one of them has FormattedPrice =0 another one has  actual price. StoreIds are like xxxxxx/0101, xxxxxx/0100. Do you know what is the reason i get 2 Skus? I have another subscription which returns only 1 Sku.

Comment: @batmaci Please check if the first SKU is a trial. If a trial is available, the Skus array will always have 2 purchasable SKUs and the first one is the trial. Otherwise, this array will only have one SKU.

Comment: yes it was trial. your answer is also correct in general but in my case, i was following all the steps correctly, problem or confusion was as I described in my answer. thank you for your help.